# enable/disable multi factor auth for the user via API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking for an Office365 API which enables me to edit the "multi factor authentication" flag for a particular user.
Currently I can do this via logging in to the azure portal (see attached)[Check the image for what I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzWjZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not available via api. I found a vote in azure feedback https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/32683693-add-mfa-status-to-user-entity-info-returned-by-gra

If MFA authentication needs to be enforced, maybe an alternative would be to have a conditional access policy requiring MFA for a group of users (e.g. the baseline MFA for admins) and check that the user is a member of that group using Graph API.